# Is it best practice to override boolean return function multiple times in java "public boolean methodF1()"

Tags: java, android

Is it good practice to override boolean return method which has the body in class A can be overridden in subclass B and C to make some more changes according to class B, C.

Language is Java, Android.

Please suggest on this.

```
class A {
    public boolean check(String arg1,String arg2){

        /*
        * Some code is here.
        * */

        return true;
    }
}

class B extends A{

    @Override
    public boolean check(String arg1, String arg2) {
         super.check(arg1, arg2);
         /*
         * Made come code change according to class B
         * */

         return true;

    }
}

class C extends A{

    @Override
    public boolean check(String arg1, String arg2) {
        super.check(arg1, arg2);
        /*
         * Made come code change according to class C
         * */

        return true;

    }
}
```

Comment: Does the `check` method always return true? If so, why does it return anything? It could have a void return type.

Comment: I don't understand. Are you asking if you have different logic, should you override the method? Yes. That is the whole point.

Comment: If the check for each class has its own logic, is ok to override that method. But is wrong to call super.check(arg1, arg2) in each child class.

Comment: I really don't understand the question.  "If a function needs to return something, so be it."  When the `check()` method is called, one of these three functions is going to be what's called.  (Possibly more, if a child calls its parent's method.)  And, "each one should just do the right thing."  No "best practice" issue here, one way or the other, IMHO.

Comment: @MarcosEchagüe Agreed. Unless there's some sort of CRUD operation done in `super.check` such as modifying something in a database, it doesn't make sense to call `super` if the result is just discarded.

Comment: Marcos:  "if you need to call `super` to get the job done, Just Do It."  And if the implementation needs to care about the return-value provided by the superclass, well, it just has to do "the right thing, whatever that may be."  It's entirely up to you and your design.  A call to the superclass would be appropriate if you need what the superclass *does,* instead of or in addition to what the child does.  "It's entirely up to you."  There's no "best practice."

Comment: One very common situation would be:  `if (super.check()) { ... do something ... test something ... } else return false;`  The subclass begins by asking its parent.  If the parent "says yes," the child might still "say no," and if the parent "says no," the child leaves it at that.  So, "the method still 'checks something,'" but here the child's implementation is *elaborating upon* what the parent does.

Answer (score 1):

It is OK to override methods if you want a behavior different from their parent one, but calling `super` is not always necessary, it depends if you want to extend the behavior or change it.

Consider the following class where we check that the length of both arguments is less that 5:

```
public class Checker {
    public boolean check(String arg1, String arg2) {
        return arg1.length() < 5 && arg2.length() < 5;
    }
}
```

You can extend the behavior to check the size but also check that both arguments start with "Bap", you can do it like this, using the parent's check() method:

```
class StartWithBapChecker extends Checker {

    @Override
    public boolean check(String arg1, String arg2) {
        boolean correctLength = super.check(arg1, arg2);

        return correctLength &&
                arg1.startsWith("Bap") &&
                arg2.startsWith("Bap");
    }
}
```

Or you can change the behavior to only check that both arguments start with "Bop", you can do it like this, ignoring the parent's check() method:

```
class StartWithBopChecker extends Checker {

    @Override
    public boolean check(String arg1, String arg2) {
        return arg1.startsWith("Bop") &&
                arg2.startsWith("Bop");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My last comment "is an answer."

A very common scenario for `class C` might look like this:

```
if (super.check(arg1, arg2)) {    
  ... do something ... test something
  ... return True or False ... 
} 
else return false;  // "what the parent said..."
```

The `check()` method in every child class begins by calling its parent's version.  If that method returns `false`, then *(say ...)* so does the child.  But if the parent returns `true`, then *(say ...)* the child does more, deciding on its own what to return.  So the child, shall we say, *elaborates upon* what the parent has done.  "All of them perform the basic check, but then the children do more."